# Setting the value in OpenXml checkbox word2013

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, openxml

So I have a document that I am editing through a WPF(C#) application.
I have successfully edited Plain Text content controls, but now I am stuck checking/unchecking the Checkboxes within the form.

I successfully find the checkbox and set the value and save the document, but the checkboxes that are set to true are never checked within the word document when I open it.

Here is the code that I use to manipulate the checkboxes.
NOTE: I access the checkboxes at the tag level, hence the field.parent.parent

```
private static void SetCheckBox(OpenXmlElement field, bool isChecked)
{
    var checkBox = field.Parent.Parent.Descendants<SdtContentCheckBox>().ToList();
    foreach (var check in checkBox)
    {
        if (isChecked)
        {
            check.Checked.Val = OnOffValues.True;
        }
        else
        {
            check.Checked.Val = OnOffValues.False;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(check.Checked.Val);
    }
}
```

When I display the values in the MessageBox they display 0/1 for true/false. So they are in fact being set.

Am I doing this properly?

Answer (score 6):

So it seems that not only must the `Checked` value for a checkbox must be set, but so must the `Text` value be changed.

So my recent code has some alterations as well, but it changes bother aspects of the checkbox.

**CODE:**

```
private static void SetCheckBox(OpenXmlElement field, bool isChecked)
{
    if (isChecked)
    {
        field.Parent.Parent.FirstChild.GetFirstChild<SdtContentCheckBox>().Checked.Val = OnOffValues.True;
        field.Parent.Parent.Descendants<Run>().First().GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = "☒";
    }
    else
    {
        field.Parent.Parent.FirstChild.GetFirstChild<SdtContentCheckBox>().Checked.Val = OnOffValues.False;
        field.Parent.Parent.Descendants<Run>().First().GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = "☐";
    }
}
```

**CONDENSED:**

```
private static void SetCheckBox(OpenXmlElement field, bool isChecked)
{
    field.Parent.Parent.FirstChild.GetFirstChild<SdtContentCheckBox>().Checked.Val = isChecked ? OnOffValues.True : OnOffValues.False;
    field.Parent.Parent.Descendants<Run>().First().GetFirstChild<Text>().Text = isChecked ? "☒" : "☐";
}
```

Comment: Is this solving your problem ?

Comment: @MaximePorté yes it is

Comment: if this code solved the issue please mark it as the answer.

Comment: How on earth did you manage to get this working. Good stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Another version of code to resolve the issue:

```
    private void ResetFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
        {
            try
            {
                string uncheckValue = "☐";
                string checkValue = "☒";

                foreach (SdtContentCheckBox ctrl in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtContentCheckBox>())
                {
                    if (ctrl.Checked.Val == OnOffValues.One)
                    {
                        ctrl.Checked.Val = OnOffValues.Zero;
                        if (ctrl.Parent.Parent.Descendants<SdtContentRun>().ToList().Count > 0)
                        {
                            SdtContentRun text = (SdtContentRun)ctrl.Parent.Parent.Descendants<SdtContentRun>().ToList()[0];
                            text.InnerXml = text.InnerXml.Replace(checkValue, uncheckValue);
                        }
                    }
                }

                doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```